# what's the cygwin/Windows equivalent of Linux' notify-send

Tags: cygwin, libnotify

Linux has the command [`notify-send`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/man1/notify-send.1.html) for sending user notifications to the desktop manager. (In many environments, these show up as pop-ups in the corner of the screen, along with low battery warnings and other system messages.) I use it in monitoring and back-up scripts.

Cygwin doesn't seem to have lib-notify, so is there a Windows equivalent for this command? Web searching has lead me to articles about running batch files from Windows' system tray/notification area, or attempts to clean the system tray up from a batch file, but I haven't found a way to produce unobtrusive user messages from background processes.

Comment: [`cygwin-ports`](http://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) promises to include notify-send, but I don't seem to be able to install it. Not sure if it's a compatibility or firewall issue at this stage.

Comment: Cygwin Ports provides `notify-send` in the `libnotify` package.  You will also need a running daemon (any of `notification-daemon`, `mate-notification-daemon`, `xfce4-notifyd`, `notify-osd`, `qtnotifydaemon`, or those builtin to the KDE and Razor-Qt desktop sessions).

Comment: Toast notifications? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868259.aspx

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try [notifu](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/). It's a kind of command line notification app, so you can use it in cygwin.

Usage: `notifu /p title /m message`

Comment: `-bash: notifu: command not found` Apparently it's available [here](http://www.paralint.com/projects/notifu/); I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: This worked for me in Cygwin. I did a  `ls -l && /c/notifu-1.6/notifu64 /m "This is a simple Notifu message."`

Comment: alias notifu='/cygdrive/c/Portabe_Program_Files/notifu/notifu.exe' and in cygwin 
    notifu /p title /m message . Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Windows has had this feature since the NT3.51 days that model after the wall(1) command in UNIX. For Pre vista,7,8 systems the command is [net send](http://ss64.com/nt/net_send.html):

```
net send * "Message"
```

On newer and professional versions it is [msg.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/msg.html):

```
msg "%username%" "Hello World"
msg * "Message"
```

Samba even has support for the older notification protocol:
    echo "Hello world" | smbclient -NM HomePC

While for the new post Vista versions one needs to use `PsExec`/`winexe`. See the [Ubuntu:SE Article on message to windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/698866/ubuntu-message-to-windows-7-not-working) for more details.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and `msg` isn't on my path. `net` is, but it doesn't have `send` in its documentation.

Comment: @daniel kaplan, Net send was dropped from vista and on. while msg.exe exists on pro and server editions as part of the messenger service. https://superuser.com/questions/1379843/windows-10-msg-command-mystery

Answer (score 2):

Try this (for Windows 10+):

https://github.com/Windos/BurntToast

Install  via Powershell (as administrator)

```
Install-Module -Name BurntToast
New-BTAppId
Import-Module BurntToast
New-BurntToastNotification
```

You can run Powershell commands inside Cygwin by doing `powershell.exe -Command 'New-BurntToastNotification'`.